# python скрипт для автоматического входа на сайт с jsp

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

Необходимо осуществить вход на сайт с помощью скрипта без использования графических инструментов через командную строку. 
Адрес точки входа http://example.ru/login.jsp
Использую примерно вот такой код

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
r = s.post('http://server.ru/login.jsp', data = {'j_username':'login', 'j_password':'password'})
```

На сайт не заходит и логин с паролем не подставляет. Как сделать правильно?

Пример jsp:

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page">
<title>server</title>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">

  <style type="text/css">
    html, body{height: 100%;}
    html, body, form, table, tr, td {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    .centerblockabsolute {
      margin: 0 auto;
      display:none;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    body {
      background-image: url(images/gradient.png);
    }
    #proxy {
      /*margin: 0 auto;*/
      /*width: 500px;*/
      /*top: -800px;*/
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin-left: -36px;
      margin-top: -64px;
      /*padding-left: 71px;*/
      /*padding-top: 300px;*/
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    label {
      color: #ffffff;
      text-shadow: #054254 0 4px 4px;
    }

    input[type=text], input[type=password]{
      border: 2px none;
      background: transparent;
      outline: 0 none;
      font-size: 13.3333px;
      width: 157px;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]{
      margin-top: -2px;
    }

    .caption {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 22px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: #96F1FF;
      text-shadow: #333333 0 5px 5px;
      position: relative;
      display: none;
      /*top: -800px;*/
      /*filter: Shadow(Color=#000000, Direction=180, Strength=5);*/
    }
    .browser-info {
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #96F1FF;
      position: relative;
      top: 154px;
      display: none;
    }
    #submit{
      /*background-image:url("images/button1.png");*/
      background-position: top left;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0 none;
      /*margin-left: 9px;*/
      position: relative;
      left: 39px;
      top: 9px;
    }
    #submit{ width:103px; height:29px; background-position:-10px -10px; }
    #submit:hover{ width:103px; height:29px; background-position:-10px -49px; }
    #submit:active{ width:103px; height:29px; background-position:-10px -88px; }

    .login-error {
      color: red;
      height: 60px;
      position: fixed;
    }

    #proxy table td {
      vertical-align: text-bottom;
    }

    #td1 {
      padding-top: 32px;
      width: 212px;
      text-align: right;
    }

    #td2 {
      padding-top: 35px;
      padding-left: 12px;
    }
    #td3 {
      padding-top: 19px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    #td4 {
      padding-top: 19px;
      padding-left: 12px;
    }
    #td5 {
      text-align: right;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    #td6 {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-left: 3px;
    }

    .webkit #td1 {
      width: 232px;
      padding-bottom: 4px;
    }

    .webkit #td3 {
      padding-bottom: 4px;
      padding-top: 17px;
    }

    .webkit #td4 {
      padding-top: 14px;
    }

    .webkit #td5 {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .webkit #td6 {
      padding-top: 7px;
    }

    .webkit input[type=checkbox] {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
    }

    #_spring_security_remember_me {
      margin-left: 17px;
    }

    .webkit #proxy {
      margin-left: -56px;
    }

  </style>
  <!--[if lte IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css">
    /*#proxy {margin-left: -120px;}*/
    #j_username, #j_password, #submit {height: 16px; font-size: 12px;}
    #proxy td {padding-top: 4px;}
    #proxy label {font-size: 13px;}
    /*#submit {height: 18px;}*/
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="background-color:#eef0ef;font-family:tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;"
      onload="load();">
<div id="js_msg" style="padding:50px;">В вашем браузере не работает JavaScript. Вам нужно включить JavaScript для того,
  чтобы работать с системой. <br><br>JavaScript does not work at you browser. You should turn on JavaScript to be able
  to work with system.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var js_msg = document.getElementById("js_msg");
  js_msg.style.display = "none";
</script>
<div id="m" class="centerblockabsolute">

<div id="background" style="background: url(images/login9.png) no-repeat fixed center #fff">
  <form name="f" action="j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=A85066B7D2FC370D1372CD1E1DE072E3" method="POST" style="height: 100%;" accept-charset="UTF-8">


    <div id="proxy">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td id="td1">
            <label for="j_username">Пользователь:</label>
          </td>
          <td id="td2" style="">
            <input  tabindex="1" maxlength="30" title="до 30 символов"
                    type='text' class="text" id="j_username"
                    name='j_username'
                    value=''/>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td id="td3" style="">
            <label for="j_password">Пароль:</label>
          </td>
          <td id="td4" style="">
            <input type='password' class="password" name='j_password' id="j_password"
                   tabindex="2" maxlength="30" title="до 30 символов"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="td5" style="">

          </td>
          <td id="td6" style="">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me"
                   id="_spring_security_remember_me"
                   title="Запомнить логин"/>
            <label for="_spring_security_remember_me">Запомнить меня</label>
            <br/>
            <input id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" type="submit"
                   value="" tabindex="3"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div>
        <div class="browser-info">
          Рекомендуемый браузер - Mozilla Firefox 4.0 и выше.<br/>
          Поддерживаемые браузеры: Google Chrome 7 и выше, Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0 и выше.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var m = document.getElementById("m");
      m.style.display = "block";
    </script>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function load(){
    document.f.j_username.focus();
    document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/login9.png)";
    document.getElementById("m").style.background = "url(images/login9.png) no-repeat fixed center #005369";
    document.getElementById("submit").style.backgroundImage = 'url("images/button2.png")';

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/login9.png";
    document.getElementById("hidden").appendChild(img);
    img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/button2.png";
  }
  (function(){
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
            body = document.body;
    var isWebkit = userAgent.indexOf("webkit") != -1;
    var isIE9 = userAgent.indexOf("msie 9.0") != -1;
    var isIE8 = userAgent.indexOf("msie 8.0") != -1;

    if (isWebkit){
      body.className = "webkit";
    }

    if (isIE9){
      body.className = "IE9";
    }

    if (isIE8){
      body.className = "IE8";
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем я остановился на таком варианте. Вроде как подошел:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import time

start_time=datetime.now()
r = requests.get('http://server.ru/login.jsp', auth=('user', 'password'))
print(r.status_code)
print(datetime.now() - start_time)
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в ответ в чем была ошибка и почему заработало. Так ответ станет полным

Comment: Применил тот же модуль, но немного иначе, первый вариант по какой то причине, не совершал вход. Этот вариант немного проще без словаря.

Comment: В сам ваш ответ :) Используйте кнопку `править`. Можно добавить, что запрос авторизации был удачен благодаря использованию специального аргумента `auth`, в котором и был передан логин/пароль. А auth с такими данными использует для авторизации: HTTP Basic Auth, и инфа об этом есть: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Comment: А вообще, я заметил что логин/пароль в вопросе вы передавали в `data`, а не в `form`, наверное поэтому ваш код и не работал, т.к. data подразумевает отправку json, а form -- form-encoded данных, которые в <form> собираются и отправляются. Скажите, а `r = s.post('http://server.ru/login.jsp', form = {'j_username':'login', 'j_password':'password'})` работает?

Comment: Не пробовал, при первой возможности попробую потестить.

Answer (score 0):

а что написанно в jsp? вы уверенны что обрабатываете пришедшие данные? например я бы в jsp прописал проверку и если данные для входа пришли, то заходить по ним и редиректить на страницу, иначе выводить форму логина и пароля, и вы уверенны что вы праильно передаете данные? `data = {'j_username':'login}'` говорит что по имени j_username лежит строка login, если вы имели ввиду что login это поле для ввода, а j_username это данные которые вы используете для входа то вам нужно писат наоборот: `data = {'login':'j_username'}`

Comment: j_username - поле в которое должен попасть текст login, а в j_password - password. и да не подумал как вызвать нажатие клавиши "вход" тогда.

Comment: А в целом я не представляю как это вообще реализовать. Поэтому то и прошу помощи.

Comment: вы можете показать что написанно в jsp? и да попробуйте изменить строку `r = s.post('http://server.ru/login.jsp', data = {'j_username':'login', 'j_password':'password'})` на `r = s.post('http://server.ru/login.jsp', data = {'login':'j_username'', 'password':'j_password'})`

Comment: будет ли достаточно такого кода чтобы осуществить вход на сайт и проверить работает он?
`import requests
r = requests.get('http://server.ru/login.jsp', auth=('login', 'password'))
print(r.status_code)`